# setBackground from Bitmap API 22+

Tags: android, bitmap, setbackground, bitmapdrawable

I have an app that can take a selected image from the users gallery and display it as their background within the app. I have used the code below with success.

```
Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,filePathColumn, null, null, null);
cursor.moveToFirst();
int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
cursor.close();
BitmapDrawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
    llmain.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
} else if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
    llmain.setBackground(drawable);
}
```

Although, since I have updated my app to API 22 it has stopped working. I have found how to set the background with

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
    llmain.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
} else if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
    llmain.setBackground(drawable);
} else {
    llmain.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, drawable));
}
```

But it doesn't work since the ContextCompat.getDrawable() call is for context and an int and not context and a BitmapDrawable.

Answer (score 0):

Little change your code i hope it's help for you

Updated:

```
Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
    String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,filePathColumn, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
    String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
    cursor.close();
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);
    BitmapDrawable background = new BitmapDrawable(getApplicationContext().getResources(),bitmap);
    llmain.setBackground(background);
```

Comment: this doesn't work due to the target for the bitmap being a LinearLayout and not an ImageView

Comment: no this still doesn't work. It just gives me a blank white background. Im now not sure if its something to do with the retrieval of the image or the setting of background part.

Answer (score 0):

Set Bitmap as background to linear layout.

Directly you can't set bitmap to layout so you should use BitmapDrawable which convert bitmap to drawable.

```
BitmapDrawable background = new BitmapDrawable(bmImg);
linearLayout.setBackgroundDrawable(background);
```

Comment: This method is depreciated. Since API 22 you can no longer do this on newer devices. It works for API 22 or less

Comment: yes,
You can use linearLayout.setBackground(background);


FYI:
 public void setBackground(Drawable background) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
    }